# WebViewJavascriptBridge not work for iPad pro(3rth generation) in iOS 13 beta 5

Tags: ios

in iOS 13 beta 5, the WebViewJavascriptBridge callback not work for wkwebview of iPad pro(3rth generation)

in iOS 13 beta 5, there is no issue in other device except for iPad pro(3rth generation).

Comment: great, but what we should do about it?

Comment: please! add your try and code information

Comment: I have found this issue. H5 have a restriction about navigator.userAgent, after iOS 13, iPad userAgent is Mac.Thanks for your ansers.